# How can I assign session id of php in a jQuery file?

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I have a main file

```
index.php
```

in which I include four other files like

```
header_get_started.php, 
content_main.php, 
right_sec_home.php, 
footer.php.
```

Here is my code

```
"index.php"

<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<?php include_once('header_getstarted.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('content_main.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('right_sect_home.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>


"header_getstarted.php"

<span class="select_input">

       <?php
         $sqlCmd = "some query";
         echo combo('cmb_command','custom-class1 custom-class2','cmd_name','cmd_id','0',$sqlCmd,'sendpostmtu()' $width="style='width:250px;cursor:pointer;'")    
       ?>

       <input type="submit" name="" class="sub_bg" value="" onclick="get_request_by_command($('#cmb_command').val());">                                   
</span>
```

In `header_get_started.php`
When select any command from select box, I want to assign it's id to `$_SESSION['id']`.

Onclick of selection box I have an ajax request which can refresh the main content (`content_main.php`). Also I want that selected id in another page in `right_sec_home.php` to refresh it's content.

How can I assign the php session id in JS file for 2nd page?

My JS file is

```
function  get_request_by_command (commandId) {
          var cmdTitle=$('#cmb_command :selected').text();

          if(cmdTitle=="") {
              cmdTitle='ABC';           
          }

          $("#main_wrap").hide();

          if(cmdTitle=='--Select--'){
              $("#cmdTitle").html("");
          }else{
              $("#cmdTitle").html(cmdTitle);
          }

          $("#cmbs_cmd").val(commandId);

          document.getElementById('request_list').innerHTML='<img src="images/loader.gif" />';

          var strURL="request_by_command_tbl.php?id="+commandId;
          var req = getXMLHTTP();

          if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {        
                    var ret = req.responseText;
                    $("#requestTitle").html("<span id='cmdTitle'>"+cmdTitle+"</span>);
                    $('#request_list').html('');
                    $('#request_list').html(ret);
                    $('#main').show();
                    $("#searchDiv").show();
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
             }              
           }
           req.open("GET", strURL, true);
           req.send(null);
         } 
}
```

With using this jQuery function, I have created an ajax request, and send the id to the `"request_by_command_tbl.php"` file.

In `"request_by_command_tbl.php"` file i assigned,

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Also I want this `$_SESSION['id']` in `right_sec_home.php` at same instant.
So is their any way to assign php `$_SESSION['id']` in the jQuery script file before sending ajax request.

My other files

```
"content_main.php"

<div id="request_list"> </div>        
    <div>  </div>
<div id="add_space"></div>
```

Right section home file in which i need session id

```
    "right_sec_home.php"

<?php

function getRequestByMonth($month, $year, $id){

        $que ="SELECT distinct(MS.date) FROM commands AS MC , ranks AS MR ,steady_tours AS MST, preferred_tours AS MPT, registration AS MMS where date_format(rm_date, '%c-%Y') = '".$month."-".$year."'
    AND    MMS.cmd_id ='".$_SESSION['id']."'    
        order by MMS.date";
        $res = mysql_query($que);
    while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($res)){}
        foreach ($rows as $res):
        if($res['date'] == "") continue;
        $dt = date("Y-n-j", strtotime($res['date'])); 
        $return[getDateB($dt)] = $res['date'];
        endforeach;
        return $return;
}
```

I hope that this is clear enough.
Any ideas?

Please help.

Comment: you cant access sessions from jquery !

Comment: @codeiz, Is their any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way for you to access the session information with jquery ..

**explanation**

sessions are files stored on the server --> where is java script is only a client side language ..

there is always a work around .. but i guess you should explain more about what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for response, I have two section on my home page and i want the session id to pass on both of them at the same instant.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean by instant .. if a session is assigned then i will stay there until the user closes the browser

Comment: Yup, right.I mean to say that my first section is refreshed with ajax request but second section shows the previous SESSION. In my case this two section are not refreshed at a time or at same instant.

Comment: For example on index.php my content_main.php section is refreshed but right_sec_home.php section shows the previous session value.

Comment: then just use jquery to replace the value of the session in the none changed frame with the new value ..! `$('.class_where_the_value_is').text()` or `.html`

Comment: Yup, I was tried this previously $('.secondary_main').html in my code but it's still shows the previous session value. My problem is $_SESSION['id'] is updated after first section is refreshed. I want to update it before.

Comment: just take the value from the refreshed page and with `$('.secondary_main').html(value_of_refreshed)` you can insert it

Comment: My 'value_of_refreshed' is kind of search functionality which depends on my $_SESSION['id'].

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $sessionId = session_id(); ?>

<input id="session_id" name="session_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sessionId; ?>" />
```

Get the value of the hidden field using jquery.

Comment: Thanks, but i have selection box and onclick of submit the particular selected value i have an ajax request in which i want to assign $_SESSION['id']

Answer (score 0):

You can use some hidden fields or script variables inside the php file.

example :

```
<script>
var id = <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
</script>
```

varible id can be accessible using the javascript or jquery